# How to make hibernate not save equal objects

Tags: hibernate, unique, equals

My equals() and hashcode() methods have been overwritten properly. But when 
I am saving equal objects, they appear in the database. How can I solve this problem? I want to have unique set of elements in the database. 
Thanks.

Here is the mapping file:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="vertical.model.filter.Filter" table="FILTER">
        <id name="id" type="long">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <discriminator column="TYPE" type="string"/>
        <subclass name="vertical.impl.filter.AbstractFilter" abstract="true">
            <set name="options" table="FILTER_OPTION" cascade="all">
                <key column="FILTER_ID"/>
                <many-to-many column="OPTION_ID" class="vertical.model.filter.FilterOption"/>
            </set>
            <subclass name="vertical.impl.services.filter.GrfFilter"
                      discriminator-value="rabota">

            </subclass>
        </subclass>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Do your objects all have the same primary key as far as Hibernate knows?

Comment: I have the large inheritance tree, but all sub-classes mapped on one interface wich has id

Comment: If more info is required, I'll post it

Comment: More information is usually a good thing. The absolutely best thing to do, though, is to build a [short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org/), with one class instead of a large hierarchy; something that would ideally fit on a single page. The benefits of this are three-fold: you will understand the problem better, you will get a solution faster, and you might even solve it before others get a chance to help you!

Comment: i've post the part of my mapping file for one class. Full example is too lagre.

Comment: Should I add constraints of composite keys to resolve id?

Comment: First of all check that set contains the non-equal objects in it before saving to DB. If your set containing equal objects as per your business equality, problem would be with your equals() method. In that case debug your Set add() method by adding duplicate entries one by one bu setting break point in your class equals() method...

Comment: Could you also show the code where you call `save` or `saveOrUpdate` to persist your objects?

Comment: some code showing `save` and the `equals` and `hashCode` overridding will be helpful. Also are you sure that your methods are not throwing any exceptions and these exceptions are not causing a rollback due to some misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a classical problem with no theoretical solution but there are practical ways of solving it.

Let me take some lines from the [article](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/09/13/dont-let-hibernate-steal-your-identity.html);

> The problem stems from differences between object identity in the virtual machine (VM) and object identity in the database. In the VM you do not get an ID for an object; you simply hold direct references to the object. Behind the scenes, the VM does assign an eight-byte ID, which is what a reference to an object really is. The problems start when you persist an object in a database. Say you create a Person object and save it to a database (person1). Somewhere else in your code you read in the Person data and instantiate a new Person object (person2). You now have two objects in memory that are mapped to the same row in the database. An object reference can only point to one or the other, but we need a way to show that these are really the same entity. This is where object identity comes in.

What you should do is simple, override the `equals()` and `hashcode()` according to the business functions of the entities.

Here is a suggested solution from the hibernate forum [article](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsAndHashCode);

> **Separating object id and business key**
>   To avoid this problem we recommend using the "semi"-unique attributes of your persistent class to implement equals() (and hashCode()). Basically you should think of your database identifier as not having business meaning at all (remember, surrogate identifier attributes and automatically generated vales are recommended anyway). The database identifier property should only be an object identifier, and basically should be used by Hibernate only. Of course, you may also use the database identifier as a convenient read-only handle, e.g. to build links in web applications.